# Fluent NHibernate One-to-Many Mapping Results in Bad Query

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a pretty simple one to many mapping using Fluent NHibernate and it works fine except the the queries NH generates are less than ideal. I found this when I checked the sql log from NH.

The query I am looking for is like

```
select p.*, c.* from parent p inner join child c on p.Id = c.parentId
```

where p.ID is the PK of the parent table and c.ParentId is a FK in the child table pointing to the PK of the parent table.

But what I found from the sql log is something like this:

```
select P.* from Parent
```

followed by a bunch of queries running against the child table like

```
select * from child c where c.ParentId = @p0
```

Not surprisingly this is causing performance issues.

My question is why NH is not generate the inner join query I think it should? What do I need to change so that NH will generate the desired query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOIN is not suitable in this scenario. It will produce SELECT resulting in more rows, then the `Parent` table has. I.e: *each* child of a parent will append new row.

The appropriate solution here is to keep these selects separated. Firstly select the parent, then load all children for all parents (just selected parents). NHibernate does have nice solution for this:

- [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)
- Fluent version described here:  [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970680/)

This would work a bit similar as you experienced. Firstly select parent, then go for child(ren). The biggest difference is, that instead of `1 + N` (going for each children collection separately) we now go for more children in batches. so it could be  1 + 2

Examples of the batch size mapping

1) Colleciton

```
HasMany<Child>(x => x.Children)
  .BatchSize(25);
```

2) Entity itself

```
public ChildMap()
{
    Id(x => x....
    ...
    BatchSize(25);
```

There are many other advantages, where the PAGING is one of the most profitable. Because we are working with a flat (not multiplied) Parent, we can apply `.Take()` and `.Skip()`

Finally, fi we would like to find some Parents based on their children, we can use in this scenario Subqueries: [15.8. Detached queries and subqueries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that and I will get back with the result.

Comment: Glad to report back the batchSize(25) sure worked in terms of cutting down the number of queries to run. We had 22 queries and now I saw 2 queries, with the first queries getting the first 12 records and the second the rest. It is pretty good. But I have a question though. Since the BatchSize on the collection is set to 25 why i am getting two queries? I am expecting one query for the number of child records (22). Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely! ;) this is exactly what we can achieve with this mapping. I would say, you really did it ;) Now you can play with this setting. I do apply this setting on *EVERY* collection AND on *EVERY* Class mapping. And why? because if you have few `many-to-one` and some `one-to-many` playing the key role in current operation... all are loaded lazily but in effective `batches`

Comment: it really made a huge difference! But you may have not seen the second part of my second comment. I asked a question on the exact effect of the BatchSize on the collection. I have 22 child records and i have set to batchsize on the child collection to 25. For this setting I expect to see one query but instead i still saw two queries, with the first retrieving first 12 records and the second the rest. I also tried to bump up the number to 50 but still got the same result. But I did get expected result when i decreased the batchsize to 10.Three queries, the first two got 10 records each.

Comment: John, I don't know the exact and correct answer here. I DO experience the same. You are RIGHT. I guess there is some "smart" calculation, some optimization... So, at the end, I know that the amout selected could be lower than the setting. But still, the total amount of SQL SELECT statements ... is less then without that setting... Sorry, I do not have better answer here ;) I am NOT the NHibernate developer, and did not dig into this as much as I could