# Mapping recursive association using nhibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have poco class

```
public class Category : Entity<int>
{
    public virtual Category Parent;
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Article> Articles {get; set;}
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Category> ChildCategories {get; set;}
}
```

I'm not sure is this correct mapping for ChildCategories property

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMapping<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
       ...
       Set(x => x.ChildCategories,
          c => { c.Cascade(Cascade.DeleteOrphans); },
          r => { r.OneToMany(); }              
       );
    }
}
```

Any child category can have only one parent. Once more is this correct mapping?
If you need more information please ask.

Update:
Exception inner message is following

```
{"Could not determine type for: xxxx, 
for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Parent)"}
```

Update 2:

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMapping<Category>
    {
        public CategoryMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));

            Property(x => x.Name, m =>
            {
                m.Length(255);
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });

            Property(x => x.Parent, m =>
            {
                //m.NotNullable(true);
            });

            Set(x => x.ChildCategories,
              c => 
              { 
                c.BatchSize(25);
                c.Inverse(true);
                c.Cascade(Cascade.DeleteOrphans); 
                c.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.Column("ParentId");
                });
              },
              r => { r.OneToMany(); }              
           );


            Set(x => x.Articles,
              c => { c.Cascade(Cascade.DeleteOrphans); },
              r => { r.OneToMany(); }
            );            
        }
    }
```

Update 3

```
Property(x => x.Parent, m =>
            {
                m.Column("ParentId");
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });
```

Error

```
{"Could not determine type for: xxxx, 
for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(ParentId)"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not so sure what the real issues is, but my standard xml mapping for parent-child collection would look like this:

```
<set name="ChildCategories" lazy="true"  batch-size="25" inverse="true">
  <key column="ParentId" />
  <one-to-many class="Category"/>
</set>
```

*While `lazy` is (as far as I remember) default, I prefer explicit statements*

I would say, that really essential is the information where to search for a **Parnet column**. This I would mapp for sure explicitly. And also the inverse and batch-size. So, following

- Adam Bar: [Mapping-by-Code - Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html)

This could be the mapping of the set

```
 ...
 Set(x => x.ChildCategories,
      c => 
      { 
        c.BatchSize(25);
        c.Inverse(true);
        c.Cascade(Cascade.DeleteOrphans); 
        c.Key(k =>
        {
            k.Column("ParentId");
        };
      },
      r => { r.OneToMany(); }              
   );
```

Few more information about why to use batch-sizing: [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970680/)

Because we used (in my snippet) the Inverse ... the Parent must be mapped as well (and assigned)

UPDATE: The **essential** part of this mapping is the **Parent** mapping!

But Parent is not a value type property. It is a reference. That's why we have to map it like this:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.Parent, m =>
{
```

See: [Mapping-by-Code - ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html)

we cannot use

```
// NOT correct mapping
Property(x => x.Parent
```

Comment: thanks, I updated code buut I'm still getting message Could not determine type for: xxxx, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Parent)"}

Comment: Could you, please, show your latest complete mapping? I suggest that you should have map for `Parent` and `Children`. Both of them. And you should use explicit `<key column="ParentId>` mapping as shown in may mapping-by-code snippet. Does it make sense? To be sure **both** Parent and child collection should/must be mapped

Comment: It has sense :) I've posted those properties on the first place. Posted above as second update.

Comment: I can see your updated mapping. The column of the `Parent` is missing. It should also be mapped to column **ParentId**. This column (ParentId) plays two roles. It is a reference column for many-to-one and also the key column for one-to-many. Then it should be working properly. Is not it?. *NOTE please, take a look here http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild to get clear idea what we have to map, it is not so much, but some parts are essential*

Comment: I'm using ModelMapperWithNamingConventions to generate column names in db, but it should match with ParentId cause it's exactly column name which should be generated.

Comment: I was blind for a while, I did not expected that... see my updated answer ... ;) ;) now it WILL work ;)

Comment: It's working now, can you confirm me that this is ok  ManyToOne(x => x.Parent, m =>
            {
                m.Column("ParentId");
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });

Comment: NOOOOO it is bad! Parent id MUST be Nullable! The root parent will never have parent right? ;)