# Rewriting postgres query to NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Please can you advise how I can write the following using NHibernate's QueryOver<>() Query<>() or other NHibernate method that will not involve me rewriting this (and numerous other similar queries) when switching DB provider?

The subqueries with multiple table joins are making this a pain for me to translate with my limited exposure of NHibernate.

```
return Session.CreateSQLQuery("select " +
                               "    boards.id, boards.name, boards.description, " +
                               "    (" +
                               "        select " +
                               "            count(topic.id) " +
                               "        from topic " +
                               "        left join users on users.id=topic.user " +
                               "        left join boards b on b.id=topic.bid " +
                               "        left join boards b2 on b2.id=b.bid " +
                               "        where (topic.bid=boards.id or b.bid = boards.id or b2.bid = boards.id) " +
                               "        and (b.type <= (:userType)) " +
                               "        and (b2.type is null or b2.type <= (:userType)) " +
                               "        and users.type > 0 " +
                               "        and users.chatban = 0" +
                               "    ) as TopicCount," +
                               "    (" +
                               "        select (max(posts.time) - max(read.time)) as t " +
                               "        from posts " +
                               "        left join users u on u.id=posts.user" +
                               "        left join topic on topic.id=posts.tid " +
                               "        left join read on read.topic=topic.id and read.userid=(:userId) " +
                               "        left join boards b on b.id=topic.bid" +
                               "        left join boards b2 on b2.id=b.bid" +
                               "        where " +
                               "            (topic.bid=boards.id or b.bid = boards.id or b2.bid = boards.id) " +
                               "            and (b.type <= (:userType)) " +
                               "            and (b2.type is null or b2.type <= (:userType)) " +
                               "            and not exists (select boardid from boardhigh where boardid=b.id and userid=(:userId))" +
                               "            and u.type > 0 " +
                               "            and u.chatban = 0 " +
                               "        group by topic.id " +
                               "        order by t desc " +
                               "        limit 1" +
                               "    ) as time " +
                               "from boards " +
                               "left join topic on topic.bid=boards.id " +
                               "where" +
                               "    boards.type <= (:userType) " +
                               (parentBoard.HasValue ? " and boards.bid = " + parentBoard.Value : "") +
                               "group by boards.id, boards.name, boards.description, boards.display " +
                               "order by boards.display desc, boards.name asc"
            )
            .SetInt32("userType", (int)UserHelper.LoggedInUser.UserType)
            .SetInt64("userId", UserHelper.LoggedInUser.Id)
            .List()
            .Cast<object[]>()
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new BoardValueObject
            {
                Id = (int)x[0],
                Name = x[1].ToString(),
                Description = x[2].ToString(),
                TopicCount = (long)x[3],
                Time = x[4] as int?
            })
            .ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I'd either make it a stored procedure which you can call with two parameters or extract that SQL to a separate view, which you can then cleanly map in NHibernate and query freely.

Comment: I'm rewriting a very large PHP project in to C# with NHibernate, this is just the first of a lot of complex queries that will need moving over. I'd like to see how this one is rewritten so I have an understanding to do the others.

Comment: both functions and views would also (potentially) require rewriting if I moved to a different DB provider, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: This is *almost* possible in QueryOver, but the second subquery in the `SELECT` clause contains a column that's grouped on but not selected. Unfortunately it's not possible to do this in QueryOver--you must `SELECT` columns you group on...

Comment: I could rewrite the 2nd subquery to be more complex and not require the group by, but this knowledge, plus the accepted answer, make me think this isn't worth while and I should just rewrite when/if needed (this query probably won't need rewriting, but there are others that will)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would heavily doubt that you'll ever recieve answer for your *giant SQL Query* - and its conversion. Meanwhile, I would like to point out some differences in approach/thinking when using NHibernate.

- Use entities first. Define your model, the business domain model with `Users`, `Topics`, `Boards`.
- Spend some time to understand the lazy loading. Lot of data could be recieved by simple query to get `User(s)`, and then nagivating to his boards, topics... All data needed will be loaded in separted SQL statements, but without complex querying.
- Do check the advantages fo [batch-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310), which is a technique how to avoid 1+N SELECT issue. It is really working well and has surprisingly large effect on amount of issued SQL statements.
- DO NOT WORRY to use native SQL to recieve "..." data required by users *(replace dots with words like crazy, unbelievable, complex)*. NHibernate is ORM at first place. It does great job for all CRUD operations related to Business object model. Any "SP like selects" are supported but indirectly... via `CreateSQLQuery`

So, try to start with simple stuff and once that is working, even the complex one will.

Comment: I'm currently doing a 2 stage rewrite of a website I have developed over the course of 10.5 years, stage 1 is just a code rewrite, with the database switchover (from postgres to sql server) happening when I have more time.
I have already generated the entity classes, mapped most of the more crucial FK relations, and (I think) I configured batch-loading but I just couldn't get this query exported correctly.
Thanks for your advice.