# nHibernate egar loading, not works when in use condition

Tags: c#, nhibernate, eager-loading

For NHibernate 3.3.3

Think about three entity like

```
public class Menu{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public IList<MenuAccess> MenuAccessList{get;set}
}

public class MenuAccess{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public Controller MenuController{get;set;}
}

public class Controller{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

consider their lazy load enabled mapping

now if in criteria query we use `SetFetchMode(FetchMode.Eager)` on `MenuAccessList` that works fine but if we create alias of `MenuAccessList` and add condition on that then `Eagerload` do not work. Throw lazy load exception if we access that later.

```
using(ISession session = NHSessionFactory.OpenSession()){
    ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Menu>();                
    criteria.CreateAlias("MenuAccessList", "ma", JoinType.InnerJoin);
    criteria.SetFetchMode("ma", FetchMode.Eager);
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("ma.MenuController.Id",10L));
    var list = criteria.List<Menu>();
}
```

This query cannot load `MenuAccessList` from menu if we access that outside session scope.

Comment: *Before you will go this way, I would suggest to re-evaluate the fetch strategy for collection. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28359510/1679310) or  [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310) are some arguments and links ... just another view...*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full name instead of the alias:

```
criteria.SetFetchMode("MenuAccessList", FetchMode.Eager);
```