# .Net with hibernate queries

Tags: .net, nhibernate, queryover

Getting error while executing the below code 
**Error:Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack**

```
public ICollection<Employee> GetEmployeeDataList(RetriveEmployeeDetailsOnEntity request)
{
    ICollection<Employee> returnValue = null;

    SectionManagerHr.Execute(() =>
    {
        using (var tx = _Dao.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var query = getEmployeeDataQuery(request);

            returnValue = query.List();
            tx.Commit();
        }
    });

    return returnValue;
}

private IQueryOver<Employee> getEmployeeDataQuery(RetriveEmployeeDetailsOnEntity request)
{
    Employee employee = null;
    EmployeeData employeeData = null;
    EmployeePayrollDefinition employeePayrollDefinition = null;

    var query = _Dao.Session
         .QueryOver(() => employee)
         .JoinAlias(() => employee.EmployeeDataList, () => employeeData, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
         .JoinAlias(() => employee.EmployeePayrollDefinitionList, () => employeePayrollDefinition, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
         .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
        .Where(() => employee.CompanyEntityId == request.EntityId);
    return query;
}
```

Comment: The error you mention " Error:Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack" is something that the DEBUGGER produces, and it's an error that happens when Visual Studio tries to show the the value of some property in debug mode. It probably has nothing to do with the real error at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that the exception you get is just wrapping the real problem:

> NHibernate.QueryException : Cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags.

Because I would expect that these are collections:

```
 employee.EmployeeDataList  // expect it is a IList<EmployeeData>
 employee.EmployeePayrollDefinitionList // IList<EmployeePayrollDefinition>
```

and they both cannot be used in ONE Query.

I would suggest to use some kind of batch fetching:

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)
- [NHibernate Fetch/FetchMany duplication in resultset, how to fix with ToFuture()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28348830/1679310)
- [How to implement batch fetching with Fluent NHibernate when working with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20995583/1679310)