# How to eager load objects in a list/collection?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, queryover

I have the following query:

```
ObjectB objectBAlias = null;
ObjectC objectCAlias = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<ObjectA>();
var results = query
    .JoinAlias(x => x.listOfBs, () => objectBAlias)
    .JoinAlias(x => objectBAlias.ObjectC, () => objectCAlias)
    .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
    .List<ObjectA>();

class ObjectA
{
    IList<ObjectB> listOfBs;
}

class ObjectB
{
    ObjectA a;
    ObjectC c;
}

class ObjectC
{
    int x;        
}
```

ObjectA has a `many-to-many` relationship to ObjectC with ObjectB being the joining table. ObjectA has a list of ObjectB's, and ObjectB has a proporty of ObjectC. I'm trying to eager load ObjectC but have had no success.

The only way I've gotten all the ObjectCs to eager load was by doing this:

```
foreach (ObjectA a in results)
{
    foreach (var b in a.listOfBs)
    {
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(b.c);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem like something that would scale very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest - do not try that *(eager loading of many-to-many)*. Instead - use built in feature:

[19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

> NHibernate can make efficient use of batch fetching, that is, NHibernate can load several uninitialized proxies if one proxy is accessed (or collections. Batch fetching is an optimization of the lazy select fetching strategy. There are two ways you can tune batch fetching: on the class and the collection level.

To get more details check these:

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)
- [NHibernate Fetch/FetchMany duplication in resultset, how to fix with ToFuture()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28348830/1679310)

> Fetching Collections is a difficult operation. It has many side effects *(as you realized, when there are fetched more collections)*. But even with fetching one collection, we are loading many duplicated rows.

Comment: So would putting a `batch-size` on ObjectB allow me to then call `result[0].listOfBs[0].c.x` outside of the session (aka eager loaded)? Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: That setting I place on both sides! 1) on `<class .. batch-size="50"` - to support effective loading for `many-to-one` and 2) on `<bag ... batch-size="50"`... exactly to support one-to-many (and many-to-many)... does it help now?

Comment: That looks like it did the trick, thanks! Any chance you could explain what it's doing?

Comment: Yes! The point here is that we use some **"optimisation" setting**. It is intended to solve the 1 + N issue. It creates some more smart selects *(with a pretty large `IN` statement)* to load as **many** entities in as a **few** DB roundtrips as possible. We than easily query over the root entity, and get all touched relations - 1) lazily and 2) in batches *(see another details here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32456516/1679310)..* hope it helps a bit. Enjoy mighty NHibernate, sir ;)