# When using nhibernate, how can I do a ThenFetch() and then bring in mulitple Properties / joins?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following code that works as part of a Fluent NHibernate query

```
session.Query<Project>()
       .Where(r=>r.IsActive)
       .FetchMany(r => r.ProjectDependencies)
       .ThenFetch(r => r.DependencyProject)
       .ThenFetch(r => r.Owner)
```

The above code works fine but the issue is that I want to now join and load some additional "attributes" that are joins off of the `DependencyProject` object besides just Owner (as above).  So I want to do something like this:

```
session.Query<Project>()
       .Where(r=>r.IsActive)
       .FetchMany(r => r.ProjectDependencies)
       .ThenFetch(r => r.DependencyProject)
       .ThenFetch(r => r.Owner)
       .AndAlsoFetch(r=>r.Status)
```

Or maybe like this:

```
session.Query<Project>()
       .Where(r=>r.IsActive)
       .FetchMany(r => r.ProjectDependencies)
       .ThenFetch(r => r.DependencyProject)
       .ThenFetch(r => r.Owner && r.Status)
```

Is there anyway to do multiple fetches of properties off of an object that is already being brought in as part of a `ThenFetch`?

Comment: **The answer**, which will at the end work for you is batch fetching, e.g. described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310

Comment: Can you clarify your comment on what I would do to batch fetch both of those properties?

Answer (score -1):

I can't test at the moment, so this may be way off base, but this could be a possible approach:

```
  var query = session.Query<Project>()
            .Where(r=>r.IsActive)
            .FetchMany(r => r.ProjectDependencies)
            .ThenFetch(r => r.DependencyProject);

  query.ThenFetch(r => r.Owner).ToFuture();
  query.ThenFetch(r => r.Status).ToFuture();

  Project project = query.ToFuture().ToList();
```